# GIMP Animation: How to merge a layer on top of all other layers?

Tags: gimp, layers, animation, merge, layer-composition

I am creating gif banner animations with GIMP and I have a product animation ready. How could I apply a layer on top of all layers of the animation? The layer would have some image and some text, if it matters.

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the[`interleave-layers` script](http://gimp-tools.sourceforge.net/animationtools.shtml) in `title` mode.

The script requires the added layer have the same size as the layers used in the animation. To do so, on the title image:

- Use `Image>Canvas size` to give the title image the same size as the frames
- In that dialog you can position your title (easy for corners and center)
- Once the canvas is enlarged, you can still position the title layer in it
- Once done use `Layer>Layer to image size` to give the layer the size of the canvas.

Another method is to:

- In the animation image, add the title as a layer:

  - drag it from another image,
  - copy/paste from another image
  - load it from file using `File>Open as layers`
- Position it
- Use `Layer>Layer to image size` to give it the same size as the others
- Make it not visible so that it isn't included in the animation

Comment: Tried that but the image has different size. Maybe I do not know how to use that, yet. I tried adding it on top of the animation and used the method you describe. What am I missing? Maybe a bulk watermark could do the same?

Comment: See edited answer